# how to generate codeigniter's form_input using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

This is my `form_input`:

```html
 <?php 
      echo form_input('noRegistrasi', isset($noRegistrasi) ? 
      $noRegistrasi : '', 'type="text" 
      class="form-control input-sm"   id="noRegistrasi" 
      placeholder="No Registrasi" id="noRegistrasi"'); 
?>
```

I want it to be dynamic, so user can add more `form_input` and therefore, I need a Javascript function.

As comparison, this is my Javascript code to generate normal HTML input `tag`.

```js
function generateSUBKLP(index) {
        var idx = document.createElement("input");
        idx.type = "text";
        idx.name = "SUBKLP" + index + "";
        idx.id = "SUBKLP[" + index + "]";
        idx.size = "10";
        return idx;
    }
```

My question is: how do I generate codeigniter `form_input()` using
Javascript?

If my question is not clear, please ask.^^

Comment: you can append the html directly.

Comment: Ans also please explain what and all will be dynamic in that..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo. Pls load jquery first

Html part:

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
        <div id="input_fields">
            <div><input type="text" name="name[]"> <input type="text" name="project[]"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="add_field"></span></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_field").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
            $("#input_fields").append('<div><input type="text" name="name[]"/> <input type="text" name="project[]"> <span id="remove" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></span</div>'); 
    });

    $("#input_fields").on("click","#remove", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also use codeigniter form_input like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = "echo form_input('username', 'johndoe');";
    $('#input_fields').append("<div>"+input+"</div>");
});
```